# mingw-w64 g++ terminates unexpectly during the compilation of wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, wxwidgets, gnu-make

I used cmake to generate MinGW makefiles to compile wxWidgets. An error was occurred during the process of make (with VERBOSE=1):

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object libs/base/CMakeFiles/base.dir/__/__/__/src/common/appbase.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\Users\frank\Documents\Codes\wxWidgets\cmakebuild\libs\base && C:\PROGRA~1\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE  -DDLL_EXPORTS -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWXDLLNAME=wxbase311u_gcc_custom -DWXMAKINGDLL_BASE -DWX_PRECOMP -D_LIB -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -Dbase_EXPORTS -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 @CMakeFiles/base.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -Winvalid-pch -include "C:/.../cmakebuild/libs/base/cotire/base_CXX_prefix.hxx"  -o CMakeFiles\base.dir\__\__\__\src\common\appbase.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\frank\Documents\Codes\wxWidgets\src\common\appbase.cpp

make[2]: *** [libs\base\CMakeFiles\base.dir\build.make:93: libs/base/CMakeFiles/base.dir/__/__/__/src/common/appbase.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/.../cmakebuild'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:469: libs/base/CMakeFiles/base.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/.../cmakebuild'
make: *** [Makefile:129: all] Error 2
```

(I've replaced the wxWidgets source path to ...)

I re-ran the the command:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE  -DDLL_EXPORTS -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWXDLLNAME=wxbase311u_gcc_custom -DWXMAKINGDLL_BASE -DWX_PRECOMP -D_LIB -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -Dbase_EXPORTS -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 @CMakeFiles/base.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -Winvalid-pch -include "C:/.../cmakebuild/libs/base/cotire/base_CXX_prefix.hxx"  -o CMakeFiles\base.dir\__\__\__\src\common\appbase.cpp.obj -c C:\...\src\common\appbase.cpp
```

But I received no output. I appended -v after the command, and here is the output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\PROGRA~1\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --with-tune=haswell --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' 'DLL_EXPORTS' '-D' 'UNICODE' '-D' 'WXBUILDING' '-D' 'WXDLLNAME=wxbase311u_gcc_custom' '-D' 'WXMAKINGDLL_BASE' '-D' 'WX_PRECOMP' '-D' '_LIB' '-D' '_UNICODE' '-D' '__WXMSW__' '-D' 'base_EXPORTS' '-D' 'wxUSE_BASE=1' '-D' 'wxUSE_GUI=0' '-I' 'C:/.../cmakebuild/lib/gcc_dll/mswu' '-I' 'C:/.../include' '-I' 'C:/.../src/zlib' '-I' 'C:/.../src/regex' '-Winvalid-pch' '-include' 'C:/.../cmakebuild/libs/base/cotire/base_CXX_prefix.hxx' '-o' 'CMakeFiles\base.dir\__\__\__\src\common\appbase.cpp.obj' '-c' '-v' '-mtune=haswell' '-march=x86-64'
 c:/progra~1/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I C:/.../cmakebuild/lib/gcc_dll/mswu -I C:/.../include -I C:/.../src/zlib -I C:/.../src/regex -iprefix c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/ -D_REENTRANT -D DLL_EXPORTS -D UNICODE -D WXBUILDING -D WXDLLNAME=wxbase311u_gcc_custom -D WXMAKINGDLL_BASE -D WX_PRECOMP -D _LIB -D _UNICODE -D __WXMSW__ -D base_EXPORTS -D wxUSE_BASE=1 -D wxUSE_GUI=0 -include C:/.../cmakebuild/libs/base/cotire/base_CXX_prefix.hxx C:\Users\frank\Documents\Codes\wxWidgets\src\common\appbase.cpp -quiet -dumpbase appbase.cpp -mtune=haswell -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles\base.dir\__\__\__\src\common\appbase.cpp.obj -Winvalid-pch -version -o C:\Users\frank\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF9vVx8.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 7.3.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 7.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.6-p2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/temp/gcc/destC:/temp/gcc/dest/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/progra~1/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/temp/gcc/dest/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/.../cmakebuild/lib/gcc_dll/mswu
 C:/.../include
 C:/.../src/zlib
 C:/.../src/regex
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/backward
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include-fixed
 c:\progra~1\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 7.3.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 7.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.6-p2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 00ba9da796d75deb4f2564304e4a9551
```

I have no idea what the output above indicates, but if I replace -E instead of -c in the original command, it runs successfully. And if I compile the precompiled source file, it also runs successfully and produces the object file I want.

With this method I can produce the object files and make recognize them, but I can't do this manually for every single object file wxWidgets needs. What problem is this? Is there a way to fix it?

CMake version is 3.13.0-rc3

GNU Make version is 4.2.1

MinGW-W64 G++ version is 7.3.0

Comment: I've temporarily fixed this issue by disabling wxBUILD_PRECOMP in option.cmake of wxWidget. But I still don't know why did g++ exited.

Comment: "*I used cmake to generate MinGW makefiles to compile wxWidgets*" Why? wxWidgets provides de `makefile.gcc` ready to use with `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc ...` Read `yourwxdir\docs\msw\install.txt`. And take a look at `yourwxdir\build\makefile.gcc` and `config.gcc`, you'll see it's not trivial.

Comment: @Ripi2 I'm currently learning to use cmake to build stuff, so I followed cmake build guide from the official wiki. I've already built wxWidgets with cmake, but I'm really curious about why g++ crashed.

Comment: Use `ming32-make` with the provided `makefile.gcc` redirecting the output to a file. See in this file the g++ commands used to compile and build each lib file. Not all commands are the same. Compare with yours.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Creating the PCH may require quite a lot of it, so one possibility is just that gcc runs out of memory and crashes. You can check whether this is the case by monitoring RAM usage in the task manager or any other similar tool while it's running.

Comment: @P.Lowell, why not use an official makefile provided to you by the library? I.e. - why do you need to run CMake and generate something that was already done for you and was givin to you by the wx core devs? Are you tryiong to learn CMake? wxWidgets? The build process?

Comment: @Ripi2 I learned that wxWidgets uses Cotire to accelerate cmake build speed, and `wxBUILD_PRECOMP` is the option of using Cotire. Since it is a cmake module, using make with `makefile.gcc` should not be affected by it. Though I've tried `makefile.gcc` as well :)

Comment: @VZ. I have 16G ram on my machine. However, I upgraded my compiler to 8.1.0 yesterday, and I compiled wxWidgets successfully with wxBUILD_PRECOMP on. So I guess maybe it's just a bug of G++ 7.3.0?

Comment: @Igor Yes I am currently learning all three of them. CMake, build systems, and wxWidgets :) I want to get familiar with CMake build process, so I generated the makefile by CMake.

Comment: @P.Lowell, trying to understand 3 completely different things at once never end well. ;) You should start with something simple - build process and CMake, then go to wxWidgets, understand its build system, and then try to use all 3 together. Or vice versa.